# Using parser5 in a typescript project

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to use parse5 in a typescript project? [parse5 home page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse5) It was written in javascript and the documentation only uses javascript as well.

```
const parse5 = require('parse5')
```

If not I have had trouble finding anything that is as fully featured as that for typescript. The main feature I need is keeping track of the location in the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any JavaScript package in TypeScript, as long as you have type definitions.

Many npm packages have corresponding type definitions (thanks to [Definitely Typed](https://github.com/definitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped)) at `@types/packagename` (example: [`@types/parse5`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/parse5)). Simply install the package (`npm i -D @types/parse5`) and TypeScript will automatically find the type definitions for `parse5`.